# How does a list in a for loop work in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

So I have this code:

```
def function(b):
   a = []
   for i in range(0,len(b),2)
       a.append(b[i])
   return a

def main():
   a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
   for i in[51,"a", 3.2]
      a = function(a)
   print a
main()
```

I don't understand how the for loop works with the list `[51, "a", 3.2]`, and why with that list it prints `[0, 8]`, but with the list`[51, "a"]` prints `[0,4,8]`.

Comment: python [for loop documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: The `[51,"a", 3.2]` is having no effect on the loop other than the fact it has 3 elements and is causing it to loop 3 times.

Comment: To learn the code step-by-step like this example, you could try this site - http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: use better variable names and do not call anythin `a` - that gets confusing very fast. You also never do anything with our outer _i_

Comment: BTW, the whole content of `function` could be replaced with `return b[::2]`

Comment: Are you aware that end of life for Python 2 was in the beginning of 2020 (and that was announced 10 years ago)? You really should switch to a recent version of Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

essentially every time you call the function it will return you only the elements form the even indexes.

you then store them back into `a` So each time your calling the function and storing the result your halfing the list storing only those from the even indexes. That values in your list [52, "a", 3.2] are only essentially tellin ghow many times to call the function.

when you call it 3 times, you will have less results than when you call it 2 times. you can see this if you put the print in side the loop

```py
def function(b):
   a = []
   for i in range(0,len(b),2):
       a.append(b[i])
   return a

def main():
   a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
   for i in[51,"a", 3.2]:
      a = function(a)
      print(a)
       
main()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[0, 4, 8]
[0, 8]
```